# LibreOffice + Cell = Macro

Tags: macros, cell, libreoffice

I only need this:

```
    A     
    -------------------
 1 | =Macro(Parameter)|
```

in other words, I need that field got the value from Macro.

Thx for now.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you want to have a UDF (User Defined Function).

http://plan-b-for-openoffice.org/ooo-help/r2.1/en-US/WIN/calc/guide/userdefined_function